# How to come back to form without reset the values?

Tags: struts, struts-1

I have a web application that is made with Java+Struts.

There is a form that when is submited it executes an Action that shows the results of the search.

Since here, all ok.

What I need is to put a link in the results page to come back to the form without erasing the search parameters.

I've put a link that goes back to the form page, but allways erase the search parameters.

I've thinking about saving and restoring this parameters to the java session, or adding the parameters to the url (like: /myForm?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3) but I think that maybe there is a better way to do this.

There is any way to do this with struts?

Pd. The struts version is 1.3.8

Comment: English isn't my native language. If something is hard to understand, please let me know and I try to add some explanations. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the parameters (/myForm?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3) to the button url that leads back to the search form. Then populate the fields using the parameters. No need to use session variables.

Unless i'm missing something...

Comment: Ok. It's simply that I don't understand why it's better create a big URL like "/myForm?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3" (this is an example but in the real case there are about 11-12 params) that store the information at session variables

Comment: Well, basically you'll need some kind of a mechanism to tell the form on the page that it should repopulate the search fields with some values. Why not store that values in session variables and pass from the link only something like "/myForm?repopulate=1", which will instruct your logic to act on it?