# Rails 4 - link back to form without reloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Rails newbie here...please be kind...

I have an app that generates a unique paragraph of text (sampled from arrays and made unique based on criteria entered in _form.html.erb, rendered from the criteria/new page). On the criteria/show page, I have 2 links, one to generate a new unique paragraph using the same criteria, and one to return to the form and edit the criteria.

For the second link, I want to retain the criteria previously entered, as the user may want to only change one entry and not have to re-enter all of it. I've found plenty of information regarding ajax calls, respond_to, remote: true, but haven't found this exact answer or if I have, my brain is TIRED and failed to comprehend.

I've seen the suggestion in a similar question ([How to come back to form without reset the values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428248/how-to-come-back-to-form-without-reset-the-values)) which talks about repopulating the data: "Just add the parameters (/myForm?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3) to the button url that leads back to the search form. Then populate the fields using the parameters. No need to use session variables." Sadly, I'm unclear about how to do implement this.

Would someone please be so kind as to walk me through either (preferably the simplest!) way of doing this?

Current links on show page (commented things are those that I tried unsuccessfully:

```
<%= link_to 'Generate Another!', criteria_path %> #regenerates text with current criteria
<%= link_to 'Enter New Information', new_criterium_path %> #this is the link I'm trying to change
<%#= link_to 'Enter New Information', new_criterium_path, :remote => true %>
<%#= link_to 'Enter New Information', { :controller => 'Criteria', :action => "new" } :remote => true %>
```

Controller new action (commented until I can make it work):

```
def new
@criterium = Criterium.new

#testing ajax stuff
# respond_to do |format|
#   format.html
#   format.json
# end
```

end

There's lots of talk about needing a new.js.erb file (or would that be show.js.erb?) and a div tag in my show(?) page but again, brain TIRED. I've attempted some of these things, then deleted from the code so as not to gak things up too much and be unable to remember what I did.

Please tell me what else you need from me in order to answer. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to pass back params to your 'new' action, and then use them when instantiating Criterium:

```
<%= link_to 'Enter New Information', new_criterium_path(criteria: params[:criteria]) %>

def new
  @criterium = Criterium.new(criteria: params[:criteria])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response!  Trying this gave me an error that clued me in to the fact that DUH, this is all completely unnecessary. I was WAY overthinking this...just route to the edit page. <facepalm>